# using function pointer in program

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have used function pointer in this, but not able to understand why it is not working, here is  my piece of code. when i run this code i get not output, i was expecting Decending order and Ascending order to be printed when i give -r in command line, and if no command line input is given it should print ascending order.

What has gone wrong in my code ??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void decending_sort()   {
   printf ("Decending order \n");
}

void ascending_sort()   {
  printf ("Ascending order \n");
}

int main( int argc, char **argv)  {

int i;
void (*sort)();

while (*++argv) {
    if ((strcmp ( *argv, "-r" )) == 0)
        sort = decending_sort;
}
sort = ascending_sort;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a call to `sort`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define `sort` as function variable, assign a value to it, but never call it, so neither `decending_sort()` nor `ascending_sort()` is ever executed.

To invoke it add this last line to `main()

```
  [...]

  sort();
}
```

---

Also: Functions without any parameters shall be declared like this:

```
void decending_sort(void);
```

Either should be a variable of their type

```
void (*sort)(void);
```

Comment: Why should i need to add sort(); line in main, i have created a function pointer and am passing the address of the function to it, it should automatically switch to that function right. Can you please explain

Comment: @user3336874: Telling the machine that an address of some function is tobe stored somewhere (as done by assigning something to `sort`) does not yet tell the machine to execute the code at that address.

Comment: @user3336874 assigning is fine, but as long as you are not calling the function using `sort()`, how it will be executed?